# What are some articles talking about best practices and trends for mobile touch screen design?

Tags: mobile, touch-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good resources about designing touch screen interfaces?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-there-any-good-resources-about-designing-touch-screen-interfaces)

Can someone direct me to either an article (e.g. Forrester) or texts that talk about touch screen UI development and, ideally, best practices or trends?

Answer (score 5):

I know of a couple of good sites, one specifically for Android and one for iPhone.
I would think there is some information which can be applied to all touch-screens.

iPhone http://pttrns.com/
Android http://www.androidpatterns.com/

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at Dan Saffers book ["Designing Gestural Interfaces"](http://www.designinggesturalinterfaces.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Are there any good resources about designing touch screen interfaces?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-there-any-good-resources-about-designing-touch-screen-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Both Win Mobile 7 and iOS have human interface guidelines available on the web. You might want to look through those, too.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218