# Do you know any good research on self-service technology (kiosk) within retail environments?

Tags: kiosk

I have been doing a fair amount of research on Self-Service Technology (SST or kiosks) UX best-practices *within a **retail** environment* and how people behave within that context.

I would like to expand my knowledge within this field.

- **So could you help me with any good articles or research papers that you have read which have good value?**

  - eg. ethnographic studies, mobile-in-retail research, cognitive psych for retail/kiosks.

*(Try to summarize the sources you link to so that people who look at this after would be able to see what they want to read at-a-glance of your answer.)*

UXSE questions from before that I am reading:

- [On designing touch-screen interfaces](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-there-any-good-resources-about-designing-touch-screen-interfaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at some of the research papers at

http://www.deyalexander.com.au/resources/uxd/kiosks.html

There are some interesting articles there and though they might be not specific to what you are looking from a retail perspective ,they do provide insights into the cognitive aspect of kiosk specific design and how that influences interactions